# Solving first order non-linear ode

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I encountered the following ODE for a function $h$:
$$
h'(x)=h(x)^2+\frac{49}{16}\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2}+\frac{a}{1+x^2}+b
$$
where $a,b$ are two constants.

For $b=0$, you can try $h(x)=(cx+d)/(1+x^2)$. However I want to find solutions for general $a,b$.

Also, I do not know how big is the solution space for each fixed $a,b$. In the case where no explicit form of solution can be written down, I still want to be able to say that there is a canonically determined function $h_{a,b}$ which is the solution to this ODE.

Thank you if you can give me some knowledge on this!

Comment: there is no solution in the known elementary functions

Comment: Then how big is the solution space? I do not have to get an explicit form. I just want to say that I have some (canonical) function $h_{a,b}$ which is the solution to this ODE.

Comment: i have only a solution by Maple

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** This answer is incorrect, since the superposition principle applies only to linear systems. But I'll leave it here.

You can break the problem down into a homogeneous solution and 2 particular solutions

$$ h(x) = h_0(x) + h_a(x) + h_b(x) $$

where each term satisfies

$$ {h_0}' = {h_0}^2 $$
$$ {h_a}' = {h_a}^2 + \frac{49}{16}\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2} + \frac{a}{1+x^2} $$
$$ {h_b}' = {h_b}^2 + b $$

Solving for $h_0$ is easy enough
$$ h_0(x) = \frac{1}{c-x} $$

$h_a$ can be found by trying the solution you stated
$$ h_a(x) = \frac{c_0 + c_1x}{1+x^2}$$

to obtain $c_0 = 0$, $c_1 = -1 \pm \sqrt{\frac{49}{16}+1}$

For $h_b$, you can try a constant for $b < 0$
$$ h_b(x) = \sqrt{-b} $$

If $b > 0$, separation of variables gives
$$ h_b(x) = \sqrt{b} \tan (\sqrt{b}x)$$

The solution space will depend on the constant in $h_0$

Comment: But then, why is your $h$ a solution to my ODE?

Comment: My mistake. I forgot that this method doesn't work for non-linear equations.